# How to scroll progressively a game object?

Tags: c#, scroll, unity-game-engine, swipe, gameobject

I am developing a game with Unity which has a main menu to allow the user select game mode. In this screenshot you can see an example:

[image: example]

My problem is the following:

I need to create a scroll in which user can put his finger on point 1 and swipe/slide to point 2. On the one hand, while this action is happening the element 2 increase its opacity and its position change progressively to the center. On the other hand, while this action is happening the element 1 decrease its opacity and its position change progressively to the left part of the screen.

Extra information:

The elements are sprites with colliders to detect the selection of the player.

What would you suggest me to do? Have you got any code to solve this? Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i think i understood your problem,
According to my understanding. You can use a binary tree for this work, u can use a sprite sheet with different level of alpha value. The variable of the binary tree responsible for changing the sprite will depend on the finger's position on the screen which you can easily get by **camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos)**. also you can easily change the position of the gameObject by recording the change in initial and final position of the touchPhase.